# Solving Quadratic Exponential Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I am having trouble with solving this equation, I need to solve for the roots of x using exponent rules, but I am having trouble in isolating this variable. Can someone help?

$$8^{x^2} -8^{-5x} = 8^6$$

So far, what I have done is:
$$
8^{x^2} -8^{-5x} = 8^6
$$
$$
8^{-5x}\left(8^{x^2+5x}-1\right)  = 8^6
$$
$$
\log 8^{-5x}\left(8^{x^2+5x}-1\right) = \log 8^6
$$
$$
-5x\log\left( 8\right) + \log\left(8^{x^2+5x}-1\right) = 6\log 8
$$
$$
\log\left(8^{x^2+5x}-1\right) = 6\log 8 + 5x\log8
$$
Here is where I am stuck. I dont know any properties to let me get the term $x^2 $ outside the log function. Can someone help?

Comment: Why would you expect there to be a pleasant, closed form solution?  I'd have thought that numerical methods were indicated.

Comment: Numerical methods were not indicated. It only said to use exponential rules.

Comment: The positive solution is approximately $x≈2.4494897\cdots$...I don't see any way to get this analytically.

Comment: most likely intended  $$8^{x^2}  \cdot 8^{-5x} = 8^6$$